# Why doesn't java honour the class path when executing a jar file with the -jar switch?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, rxtx

This works:

```
$ java -cp ".:/PATH/TO/RXTXcomm.jar:./jobexftp.jar" -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni com.lhf.jobexftp.StandAloneApp
JObexFTP 2.0 beta (15/10/2010)
Java Obex File Transfer Protocol application and library
Developed under/using 100% free software.
For more information access: http://www.lhf.ind.br/jobexftp/

Usage: jobexftp <serialPort> [<commands>] [<options>]
...
```

This doesn't:

```
$ java -cp ".:/PATH/TO/RXTXcomm.jar" -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -jar jobexftp.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/io/NoSuchPortException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
```

I found the class name to execute (for the first example) in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file, inside the jar:

```
Main-Class: com.lhf.jobexftp.StandAloneApp
```

Why does executing the jar file, with the -jar switch seem to cause Java to ignore the classpath and fail to find the `gnu/io/NoSuchPortException` class in RXTXcomm.jar?

---

On an older machine, running Java 1.6, I can execute the jar file without needing a classpath.  How does this work?

```
$ env | grep CLASS
$ env | grep JAVA
$ java -jar jobexftp.jar 
JObexFTP 2.0 beta (15/10/2010)
Java Obex File Transfer Protocol application and library
Developed under/using 100% free software.
For more information access: http://www.lhf.ind.br/jobexftp/

Usage: jobexftp <serialPort> [<commands>] [<options>]
...
```

---

The reason it worked on the old machine is that it had a copy of RXTXcomm.jar in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.21/jre/lib/ext/.

```
$ ls -lA /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.21/jre/lib/ext/RXTXcomm.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 137764 2011-02-17 16:58 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.21/jre/lib/ext/RXTXcomm.jar
```

Making a new `ext` directory in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre and copying `RXTXcomm.jar` into it *doesn't* get rid of the error on Java 1.8.

Comment: Because it would be a contradiction in terms. The JAR file is supposed to be self-contained and self-describing, containing iits own Main-class and Class-path attributes.

Comment: @EJP how did this use to work with Java 1.6, where I can execute the jar file (with the -jar switch) without even needing to specify a classpath - how did Java 1.6 find its way to RXTXComm.jar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-jar` switch is intended to launch the jar as a self contained program. As stated in the `java` man page:

> When you use the `-jar` option, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored.

To provide a classpath, use the `Class-Path` entry in the manifest file.

Further reading: [The Java™ Tutorials: Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Comment: Thanks, my confusion is because the *same* jar file executes correctly on an older Ubuntu box (Java 1.6) without even needing the classpath to be set on the command line.

Comment: I'm no expert when it comes to JNI stuff, but presumably your previous serup had a different VM, different runtime library and/or a different system classpath setting.

Answer (score 1):

you can modify the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file and add `Class-Path` entry.

in maven build system you can config it like below

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>your.main.Class</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>./config/</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

from the `man java` we can confirmed this issue `When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.`

Answer (score -1):

You need to copy also the .so/.dll to the jni folder. 
Ubuntu RXTX didn't used to work well. 
Check out [this](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_on_Linux)